# Issue with "Mini Calendar" on Outlook 2010

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, calendar

In Outlook 2010, the "Mini Calendar" data is all zeroes – the month name, the days, everything.

I repaired Outlook with no issues, but the Mini Calendar issue persists. I'm sure a uninstall and reinstall would fix the problem, but it's just strange and I'm wondering what the cause may be for this.

The large Calendar which I would assume is where the Mini Calendar obtains its information from is functioning just fine. It is only on the Mini one (in the top left of the screen) with the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Figured I would answer this in-case someone has this issue in the future.

It seems we had MSoutlook font as the Calendar font and it was not installed on the computer, so I changed it to Arial and it corrected the "wingding" mini calendar issue.  Hope this helps someone some day, not a "save the day" answer, but something to quit scratching the head over.

-Good Day